# Отображение в родительском окне изменений в iframe

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт, на подобие fancybox, который умел бы как fancybox в модальном окне, открывать другую страницу сайта, но при этом, изменения в iframe окне фиксировались и в родительском.

У меня есть интернет магазин - на нем есть функция быстрого просмотра. Так же в магазине ajax корзина.

И вот если я в обычной странице куплю товар, то в корзине появится товар, но если куплю его через быстрый просмотр, то товар не появляется там сразу, а только после перехода на другую страницу или обновления родительской.

Вот пример `http://soins.ru/index.php?cat=3`

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написали `iframe` использовать не стоит.
Вместо него можно сделать так

```
$.get(url, function (req) { $("#popup").html(req) };
/*
    url - путь к странице, которая выводит быстрый просмотр, 
    данные передаются в GET, но можно и POST( тогда $.post )

    $("#popup") - это ваш попап, который будет 
    получать данные и выводить их на экран
*/
```

Преимущество в том, что можете использовать скрипты как и на страницах с товарами, все будет работать в одном контексте

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вообще iframe в предпросмотре использовать? Используйте ajax.

Костыльный вариант - обновляйте корзину при закрытии fancybox с iframe.

Comment: я не знаю как (((

Comment: @KoVaLsKy если совсем никак есть фриланс. можно подсказать как сделать или исправить ошибку если есть, но не сделать всю работу за Вас.

Answer (score 0):

из iframe обращайтесь к window